# want to print a particular cell's all the row values in excel in java

Tags: java, selenium

After getting a paticular item name and price I store it in excel sheet. Now I compare their price and get lowest price, but how can i print that lowest price all detail

my code is

```
public static void getMinPhonePrice() throws Exception {

        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\demo.xlsx"); 

         FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);

            XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
            String min = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
            int value_min = Integer.parseInt(min.substring(1).replace(",", ""));

            String getText = null;
            XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
             getText =  sh1.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
             System.out.println(getText);
            }



            for (int i = 1; i <=sh1.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

                String c =  sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

                int value = Integer.parseInt(c.substring(1).replace(",", ""));

                if(value < value_min) {
                    value_min=value;
                    for(int k=0;k<3;k++) {
                    getText = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(k).getStringCellValue();

                     System.out.println("minimum item detail"+getText);
                    }


            }

        }    

        }
}

but it not printing my minimum item detail
```

Comment: Is in your excel like this : `row1` : `redmi7 | 7988 | flipkart` ? they are available in different cell `cell1 | cell2 | cell3`?

Comment: in row1 there is 3 cell

Comment: What the value each cell ?

Comment: in cell1- redmi7,cell2 -7988,cell3-flipkart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you don't need nested loop, and you need store other cell to string variable. Please try the bellow code.

```
    File file = new File("phone_compare.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(file);

    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
    String min = wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
    int value_min = Integer.parseInt(min.substring(1).replace(",", ""));

    String getText = null;

    String str1 =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
    String str2 =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
    getText = str1 +" " +value_min +" " +str2;
    XSSFSheet sh1= wb.getSheetAt(0);


    for (int i = 0; i <=sh1.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

        String c =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();

        int value = Integer.parseInt(c.substring(1).replace(",", ""));

        if(value < value_min) {
            value_min=value;
            str1 =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
            str2 =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();
            getText = str1 +" " +value_min +" " +str2;



    }

}    
System.out.println(getText);
}
```

Comment: hi @Frian .i dont want to write column value manually.when am using for loop why its not printing anything

Comment: if(value < value_min) {
    value_min=value;
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
    String getText =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
    
    System.out.println(getText);
    }

Comment: you want print all value each row ?

Comment: not all value .only minimum price corresponding row

Comment: i mean if i have 6 or 7 column then should i use manually to print this....i am trying to use for loop .but it doesnt print anything

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean, maybe this is ? `col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col7`, please tell the output what you want

Comment: see here i have only 3 column thats why we manually write  str1 =  wb.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

Comment: but if i have 6 no of column .there we must apply for loop to get minimum price corresponding row value

Comment: can u understand what i want@Frian

Comment: ohhh...it's simple, you can get value each cell by `.getCell(0)` change count `0` with you want, it's index. Example if you want get col 6, then to be `.getCell(5)`

Comment: so now you have 6 column each row ? and you want to print all cells in the row that have the smallest value ?

Comment: yes.but i dont want to print all cells in the row that have smallest value manually.i want for loop